# Get database table row count javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I need to display via a html page the number of rows within my sql database table. with javascript. I cant use php as the frontend of the template is all html.

The admin section of my site uses php and uses the following code to get the number or rows within my channel table.

```
<?php $qry="select * from channel";
                    $res=mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($res);

                        ?><?php echo $rowcount; ?>
```

How can I reproduce the same using html and javascript.

Thanks

Comment: is you non admin section not served by php as well? what have you tried?

Comment: How is your non-admin section getting data? Is your PHP code exposing some data as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

What will you count in HTML?
If all rows are displayed as HTML table rows, you could count them. Otherwise you couldn't count rows in a SQL-table to which you don't have access from the frontend.

Counting rows of an HTML table with id="mytable" would look like this:

```
var num_rows = $('table#mytable tr').size();
```

Comment: sorry for the the long reply time. I got this issue fixed. Thanks for your help.